# How to call function on button click?

Tags: java, processing

I have a Processing class, called Button, which has the following function `onClick`:

```
class Button() {
    // Extra code
    void onClick() {
        // Run function here
    }
}
```

which is supposed to trigger a function call when the button is clicked, and the function is taken in from an argument, like so:

```
Button test = new Button(..., callFunction())
```

Where `callFunction()` is guaranteed to be a `void` function. How do I call the function `callFunction()` once `test` is clicked on? I can check if the button is clicked, but I have no idea how to wire that to a function call provided by an argument.

Comment: Java is all about classes and interfaces. Even lambda expressions are kind of mapped to interfaces. So no method or function reference. You have to define your function using a Runnable or a Consumer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use **Runnable**.

```
Button test = new Button(..., new Runnable(){

     public void run() {
         // your stuff.
         callFunction();
     }
});
```

Then:

```
class Button() {

    private Runnable runnable;

    public Button (... Runnable runnable ){
       this.runnable  = runnable;
    }

    // Extra code
    void onClick() {
        runnable.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't I need to use an import to use this? What import do I use?

Comment: It's standard java: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html

Comment: What is "runnable" in onClick? From what I see it's an undefined variable.

Comment: Well. in the constructor you pass a runnable object.. so you should save it as a private member of the class Object. I've edited my example

Comment: This doesn't work - Processing errors on the `runnable.start()` line, saying `start() is not a function` for some reason.

Comment: I think that sould be `runnable.run()`.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure of this serves your purpose. But an external handler can be handy.

```
class Button {
    // Extra code
    private ClickHandler handler;

    //Constructor
    Button(..., ClickHandler handler) {
        this.handler = handler;
    }
    void onClick() {
    // Run function here
        handler.handle();
    }
}

interface ClickHandler {
    void handle();
}
```

Now you can create your object like:

```
Button test = new Button(..., new ClickHandler() {
    public void handle() {
        //do your stuff.
    }
});
```

Note: Probably Java 8 supports callback function references through lambdas.

Comment: That needs to be `public void` - but otherwise, it works! Thanks!

Comment: @Qwerp-Derp I have edited the code, thanks for pointing it! If it helps, you might also like to accept the answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [Processing Button example](https://processing.org/examples/button.html).

It's not encapsulated into a class, that is up to you to implement, 
but it does illustrate how to handle events using Processing's built-in `draw()` and `mousePressed()` methods.

If it helps, here's a button class I use in some of [my sketches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23189470/processing-having-object-oriented-programming-issues/34792466#34792466):

```
int numButtons = 3;
Button[] buttons = new Button[numButtons];

void setup(){
  size(180,200);

  int buttonWidth = 150;
  int buttonHeight = 50;
  int buttonSpacing = 15;

  for(int i = 0 ; i < numButtons; i++){
    buttons[i] = new Button("button "+(i+1),buttonSpacing,(buttonHeight+buttonSpacing) * i,buttonWidth,buttonHeight);  
  }
}
void draw(){
  background(255);

  for(int i = 0 ; i < numButtons; i++){
    buttons[i].update(mouseX, mouseY, mousePressed);
    buttons[i].draw();
  }
}
//hacky way callback the main sketch from a button - look into callbacks
void onButtonClicked(Button b){
  println(b.label,"was pressed at",new java.util.Date());
}

class Button{
  float w,h,x,y;//width, height and position
  color bg = color(200);//background colour
  color fg = color(0);//foreground colour
  String label;//button label

  boolean isOver,wasPressed;
  int pw = 10;
  Button(String label,float x,float y,float w,float h){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.w = w;
    this.h = h;
    this.label = label;
  }
  //mouseY,mouseY,mouseDown
  void update(int mx,int my,boolean md){
    //it's over if it's within the button's bounding box
    isOver = ((mx >= x && mx <= (x+w))&&(my >= y && my <= (y+h)));
    //if it's over and pressed it's a click
    if(isOver && md){
      //if it wasn't pressed before, trigger click callback
      if(!wasPressed){
        onButtonClicked(this);
        wasPressed = true;
      }
    }else wasPressed = false;
  }

  void draw(){
    pushStyle();
      noStroke();
      fill(isOver ? fg : bg);
      rect(x,y,w,h);
      fill(isOver ? bg : fg);
      text(label,x+pw,y+h*.75);
    popStyle();
  }
}
```

You may be required to implement it differently, but hopefully this will give you some ideas.

**Update**
If feels like the callback is the main thing you're after.
If that's the case, one option is to use [Java Reflection to invoke a Method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/methodInvocation.html).

Here's a modified version of the above Button class that takes a class that contains the callback method and the name of the callback method as arguments:

```
import java.lang.reflect.*;

int numButtons = 3;
Button[] buttons = new Button[numButtons];

void setup(){
  size(180,200);

  int buttonWidth = 150;
  int buttonHeight = 50;
  int buttonSpacing = 15;

  for(int i = 0 ; i < numButtons; i++){
    buttons[i] = new Button(this,"onButton"+(i+1)+"Clicked","button "+(i+1),buttonSpacing,(buttonHeight+buttonSpacing) * i,buttonWidth,buttonHeight);  
  }
}
void draw(){
  background(255);

  for(int i = 0 ; i < numButtons; i++){
    buttons[i].update(mouseX, mouseY, mousePressed);
    buttons[i].draw();
  }
}
public void onButton1Clicked(){
  println("button 1 clicked");
}
public void onButton2Clicked(){
  println("button 2 clicked");
}
public void onButton3Clicked(){
  println("button 3 clicked");
}

class Button{
  float w,h,x,y;//width, height and position
  color bg = color(200);//background colour
  color fg = color(0);//foreground colour
  String label;//button label

  boolean isOver,wasPressed;
  int pw = 10;

  Object parent;
  Method callback;

  Button(Object parent,String callbackName,String label,float x,float y,float w,float h){

    this.parent = parent; 
    try{
      callback = parent.getClass().getMethod(callbackName);
    }catch(Exception e){
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.w = w;
    this.h = h;
    this.label = label;
  }
  //mouseY,mouseY,mouseDown
  void update(int mx,int my,boolean md){
    //it's over if it's within the button's bounding box
    isOver = ((mx >= x && mx <= (x+w))&&(my >= y && my <= (y+h)));
    //if it's over and pressed it's a click
    if(isOver && md){
      //if it wasn't pressed before, trigger click callback
      if(!wasPressed){
        //onButtonClicked(this);
        if(callback != null){
           try{
            callback.invoke(parent);
          }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
          }
        }
        wasPressed = true;
      }
    }else wasPressed = false;
  }

  void draw(){
    pushStyle();
      noStroke();
      fill(isOver ? fg : bg);
      rect(x,y,w,h);
      fill(isOver ? bg : fg);
      text(label,x+pw,y+h*.75);
    popStyle();
  }
}
```

That's one way to tackle it. Be sure to dig deeper into java reflection and the Method class if you need arguments for those callbacks.

Comment: That's what I'm planning to do, after I'm finished with this problem - also, you haven't answered my question, IMO you've glided around it a bit.

Comment: If the callback is the main thing you're after, have a look at the updated answer above

Answer (score 0):

I will assume that you are using Java 8. If you aren't, you should! As one of its main improvements over older versions is precisely working with functions as parameters.

To pass a function object (i.e. a lambda) as a parameter, you first need to define a functional interface to somehow "hold" the implementation of your function. A functional interface can be any interface with just one method, like this:

```
interface MyFunction {
    public void call();
}
```

Declare it wherever you want, even inside your `Button` class. Doesn't matter as long as `Button` can access it.

Then you just tell your `Button` constructor that the last argument is a function, store it as a private field, and call it later when the button is clicked:

```
class Button() {
    MyFunction buttonFunction;
    public Button(..., MyFunction myFunction) {
        // ... other initialization ...
        buttonFunction = myFunction;
    }
    // Extra code
    void onClick() {
        // Run function here
        buttonFunction.call();
    }
}
```

To pass your function as a parameter, do it like this:

```
Button test = new Button(..., () -> callFunction());
```

You don't need to create an anonymous `MyFunction` class, nor override anything. Java 8 figures all that out for you. It knows that the `Button` constructor expects a `MyFunction` parameter, and it knows that `MyFunction` only has one method, `call()` with no parameters; so when you provide a function body with no parameters, Java knows that it is the implementation for `MyFunction#call()`.

In fact, you don't even need to define an interface: you can just replace `MyFunction` with `Runnable` and `call()` with `run()`, and everything will work as intended, because `Runnable` is also a functional interface:

```
class Button() {
    Runnable buttonFunction;
    public Button(..., Runnable myFunction) {
        // ... other initialization ...
        buttonFunction = myFunction;
    }
    // Extra code
    void onClick() {
        // Run function here
        buttonFunction.run();
    }
}

Button test = new Button(..., () -> callFunction());
```

But it's better to know the basics first!

Comment: Processing doesn't support Java 8, unfortunately... :(

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that. In that case, Mariano's answer is the best one -- just replace `start()` with `run()`.