# Processing - How to stop shape from disappearing when making another

Tags: processing

The code that I currently have allows me to create a rectangle using `mousePressed()` and `mouseDragged()`. However, when I start to create another one, the rectangle that I made before disappears.

I simply want my program to create a rectangle and not have it disappear when creating another one.

I also want this to work with the `background()` inside the `draw()` function because whenever I remove `background()` from the program or place it inside `setup()` I am unable to reduce the width and height of the shape when dragging the mouse and it creates small trails of rectangles inside the shape which occurs when the mouse is also being dragged.

Here's my code

```
int a, b, c, d = 0;

void setup() {
  size(1000, 800);

}


void draw() {
  background(204);
  stroke(0);
  strokeWeight(2);
  noFill();
  rect(a, b, c, d);
}


void mousePressed() {
  a=mouseX;
  b=mouseY;
}


void mouseDragged() {
  c=mouseX-a;
  d=mouseY-b;
  rect(a, b, c, d);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you could use another layer to draw onto (without clearing it).
Luckily that's easy to do using [PGraphics](https://processing.org/reference/PGraphics.html):

```
int a, b, c, d = 0;

PGraphics layer;

void setup() {
  size(1000, 800);
  stroke(0);
  strokeWeight(2);
  noFill();
  // make new drawing layer
  layer = createGraphics(width, height);
  // use drawing functions within beginDraw() / endDraw()
  layer.beginDraw();
  layer.stroke(0);
  layer.background(204);
  layer.strokeWeight(2);
  layer.noFill();
  layer.endDraw();
}


void draw() {
  background(204);
  // render background layer
  image(layer,0,0);
  // draw foreground;
  rect(a, b, c, d);
}


void mousePressed() {
  a=mouseX;
  b=mouseY;
}


void mouseDragged() {
  c=mouseX-a;
  d=mouseY-b;
  // draw preview
  rect(a, b, c, d);
}

void mouseReleased(){
  // render final shape into background layer
  layer.beginDraw();
  layer.rect(a, b, c, d);
  layer.endDraw();
}
```

If you decide to have fun making a drawing tool you might want to see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23189470/processing-having-object-oriented-programming-issues/34792466#34792466).